# Google map Polygon gives uncaught typeerrors when calling containsLocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I include the map functionality with the script line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing&sensor=false"></script>
```

the complete code is this

```
var map, currentInfoWindow, drawingManager, selectedShape;
var markers = [];
var selectedMarkers = [];
var shapes = [];

function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng({0},{1}), // this comes from the db
    zoom: 8,
    tilt: 30
};

var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapDiv');
var height = Math.max(0, document.documentElement.clientHeight - 110).toString();
mapDiv.setAttribute('style','height: ' + height + 'px');
map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

// {2} 
// here I create the markers with db info, it works fine
// var marker{0} = new google.maps.Marker({{ position: new google.maps.LatLng({1},{2}), map: map, title: '{3}', icon: pinImage{0} }}); markers.push(marker{0});

drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
    },
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
    shapes.push(polygon);            
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);  
    var newShape = polygon.overlay;                                  
    google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
        setSelection(newShape);
    });
    setSelection(newShape);                                        
});

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btnDeleteSelectedShape'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btnDeleteAllShapes'), 'click', deleteAllShapes);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btnSelectMarkers'), 'click', setSelectedMarkers);
}

function addInfoWindow(marker, content) {
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    if (currentInfoWindow != null) {
        currentInfoWindow.close(); 
    }

    infoWindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
    currentInfoWindow = infoWindow;
});
}

function markerSelection(spanTitle, button) {
var hidden = document.getElementById('hiddenTitle');
hidden.value = spanTitle.textContent;
button.disabled = true;
__doPostBack('','');
}

function clearSelection() {
if (selectedShape) {
  selectedShape.setEditable(false);
  selectedShape = null;
}
}

function setSelection(shape) {
clearSelection();
selectedShape = shape;
shape.setEditable(true);                                
}

function deleteSelectedShape() {
if (selectedShape) {
  selectedShape.setMap(null);
}
}

function deleteAllShapes() {
for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    shapes[i].overlay.setMap(null);
}
shapes = [];
}

function setSelectedMarkers() {
var hidden = document.getElementById('hiddenTitle');
for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[k].getPosition().lat(), markers[k].getPosition().lng());
        console.log(point);

        if ($.inArray(markers[k], selectedMarkers) == -1 
            && google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, shapes[i])) 
        {
            selectedMarkers.push(markers[k]);
            alert(selectedMarkers.length);
            hidden.value += markers[k].getTitle() + ',';
            alert(hidden.value);
        }
    }
}
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I suspect the code with the 'polygoncomplete' may be wrong as well as I have been getting javascript errors at that part too.

Comment: There are syntax errors in the posted code ("{{"). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: you can ignore that, i write the code with c# and in the code behind it is asking for those double braces

Comment: Where are you creating your `markers` and `selectedMarkers` arrays?  Add that code to the question

Comment: My browser doesn't ignore it.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue (second request).

Comment: here's all the code, forgive me if i have forgotten any braces!

Comment: you are mixing the variables `k` and `i` in the `for`-expressions

Comment: We don't need _all_ your code, just a minimal example that you have tested and know exhibits the issue. What part of "Complete" didn't you understand?  As duncan commented, there are no markers in your posted code (still).  Please add some sample markers.  It would have been useful if you had added the required HTML/CSS so we didn't have to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

the error was on this line

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, shapes[i]))
```

it works fine when written like this

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, shapes[i].overlay))
```

@Dr.Molle thank you for spotting that loop error